# Swagger fails with CORS-style error

Tags: javascript, java, xmlhttprequest, cors, swagger

```
Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.
```

I've had this error before, but I could really do with having Swagger UI work this time. The json file I'm putting the URL in for is being served from the same host, so it shouldn't require CORS. Indeed I've enabled CORS on the server side but it's not adding the headers because the browser isn't sending an Origin header (presumably because it knows CORS isn't required).

In fact the json file returns a 200 and I can see the content of it in the response in the Chrome debug tools network tab - infuriatingly there isn't a failed request in there so I don't know what's broken, other than that the petstore URL does work.

ETA: Swagger Editor *can* call my API without these issues, even when it is hosted on another server, but it's Swagger UI I want to share with users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was nothing to do with CORS, whatever the issue was.

Replacing the JSON file with one taken from the petstore worked, so it must've been some issue parsing it.